# What is this address format that the cardano wallet API is returning to me

Tags: cardano-address

I am using API.getUsedAddresses in the browser and I am being returned an address unlike the standard addr1..... that I am used to.

If I enter it into cardanoscan, it takes me to the wallet that I would expect, and the different string is displayed just below the main address.

Example of what is returned to me: 0107e8756919dc24322e2c149164b8d24255852fa9a4fcc0bb7155c3c112a080bd4a48b80af3e7f9d980350acd4cc31b70721b410506e867c0

Do I need to convert it to a different base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that address is just hex encoded. The address starting with `"addr1"` is Bech32 encoded.

Where is that `API.getUsedAddresses` function coming from? Its does not seem to be part of the Haskell API in `cardano-api`.

Comment: That would make sense, thanks! The getUsedAddresses function comes from CIP-30 in the dApp wallet web bridge.